# How to enable Space Mouse in packaged UE game?

Tags: navigation, packaging, unreal

I've got Space Mouse Wireless functioning correctly in Editor and Play mode (UE 5.0.3 Windows 11), but when I package I lose rotation and pitch. This same behavior was happening in Editor before scripting some nodes in level BP. Why wouldn't these pass onto a packaged game? And is there a way to ensure full 6-axis mappings to begin with, suspect I shouldn't have to script anything, simply enable the plugin.

Here's the BP used to get Space Mouse working in Editor and Play mode: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9sPn.jpg) I simply packaged the game, only unexpected behavior is no control over rotation and pitch (rotation on Z and Y).